# Spring retry template with proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I have a RestTemplate that has a proxy set up such as

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(config.getProxyHost(), config.getProxyPort()));
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Now I also tried this with RetryTemplate and it does not work obviously there is no constructor like this

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate(requestFactory); // does not work
```

Is there any way to set the proxy settings to RetryTemplate as it is for RestTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. The proxy is for talking over HTTP, the retry template has nothing to do with HTTP.

If you want to retry calls to your rest template, use

```java
... = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
    return restTemplate....();
}
```

Comment: ah right, I didn't get it then, I got it confused because names seemed similar, didn't check the docs much... thanks for clarification!